# unable to add border bottom in react native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to make a registration form.

I created a file named Regform.js under the component directory.

I am unable to get border-bottom for the text Registration

Here is the demo link [demo working link](https://snack.expo.io/@chaitu111/project-1)

please let me know, where I am doing wrong

[image]

Component/Regform.js

```js
import * as React from 'react';  

import {   
 Text,   
 View,   
 StyleSheet,    
 TextInput,  
 TouchableOpacity   
 } from 'react-native'; 


 export default class Regform extends React.Component {  
  render() {  
   return (  
    <View>  
     <Text style={styles.header}> Registration </Text> 

      <TextInput style = {styles.textinput}
      underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
      placeholder = "Enter Your Name"
      placeholderTextColor = "#9a73ef"
      onChangeText = {this.handleName}/>

      <TextInput style = {styles.textinput}
      underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
      placeholder = "Enter Your Email"
      placeholderTextColor = "#9a73ef"
      autoCapitalize = "none"
      onChangeText = {this.handleEmail}/>

    </View>  
   );  
  }  
 } 


 const styles = StyleSheet.create({  

      header: {  
        fontSize: 36,
        alignself: 'self',
        color: 'red',
        marginBottom: 30,
        borderBottomColor: 'red',
        borderBottomWidth: 2
      },
      textinput: {
        fontSize: 18,
        alignself: 'self',
        color: 'black',
        marginBottom: 30,
        borderBottomColor: 'grey',
        borderBottomWidth: 2
      }
  });
```

Comment: The border is present in your screen

Answer (score 99, accepted):

It seems `borderBottom` doesn't work for the Text component. You can either add a `View` wrapper and supply `borderBottom` to it **or** add a `TextInput` and make `editable={false}`

```
<View style={styles.headerWrapper}>
    <Text style={styles.header}> Registration </Text>
 </View>
...

headerWrapper: {
    borderBottomColor: 'red',
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    marginBottom: 30,
},
header: {
    fontSize: 36,
    alignSelf: 'auto',
    color: 'red',

},
```

Comment: I tried using this in my ```selected``` styles such that when I click on the text, it gets underlined. I wanted to increase the width of the underline so tried using borderBottom instead of underline but it doesn't work for me. Could you take a look? https://snack.expo.io/@saachitech/da6280

Answer (score 2):

The more accurate answer is that only IOS doesn't support it. Follow this discussion and probably it would be fixed https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23537

[image]